# Display error when i try to composer install

Tags: laravel, cmd, composer-php

I have one laravel5.0 project
I want to run this project in my local system
But when i run command into cmd "composer install" 
that time my cmd display following error message

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel5>composer install
> php artisan clear-compiled

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel5\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): fai
led to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel5\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel5\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htd
ocs\Laravel5\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


[RuntimeException]
Error Output:


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just run this command

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

It will run composer without any scripts.